# Insert .txt file into MySQL Error: 2

Tags: mysql, compiler-errors, filepath, load-data-infile, file-io

Getting an error after inserting .txt file `NamesInfoTable(1)` into MySQL table `nameinfo`

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/NamesInfoTable(1).txt' INTO TABLE NameInfo;
ERROR 2 (HY000): File '\path\NamesInfoTable(1).txt' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

.txt file Description

```
“Arabic”, “Obsolete”, “High”, “5021”, “900012222”, “1260”, “01/12/13”

“English”, “Historical”, “Low”, “5022”, “900012223”, “1261”, “02/15/13”

“German”, “Colloquial”, “Medium”, “5023”, “900012224”, “1262”, “03/01/13”

“Russian”, “Current”, “Medium-High”, “5024”, “900012225”, “1263”, “06/01/13”

“Chinese”, “Low”, “01/15/13”
```

Table Description

```
CREATE TABLE NameInfo (
Language VARCHAR (5),
Status  VARCHAR (5), 
Standard VARCHAR (4),
Name VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
Name_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
Place_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
Supplier_ID INT (4)NOT NULL,
Date_Supplied DATE, 
PRIMARY KEY (Name_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Supplier(Supplier_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Place_ID) REFERENCES Place(Place_ID)
);
```

Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Comment: Can the account that MSQL is running under see the path? \path\NamesInfoTable(1).txt

Comment: @PreetSangha how can I tell if MySQL can see the path?